# Query that calculates a DateDiff returns a Data Type Mismatch in criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query that returns the products that have less than a month until their expiration date.
In one column I'm using a DateAdd to, based in the receive date of the product, know when is the expiration date. Then in another column I'm using a DateDiff to calculate the days until the expiration date so that I could apply a criteria of <30.
The problem is that the query runs normally but in the moment that I write <30 in Criteria, it gives me a data type mismatch error. I've tried a bunch of different things to avoid this, such as write in criteria of DateAdd <Date() + 30, or do another query where I calculate the second part, or put the <30 in the expression builder so that it returns a 0 or -1, but even with that result, I can't use a criteria to have just the results that I want, but nothing worked.

Product table
| ProductName | EstimatedDuration |
| ----------- | ----------------- |
|      A      |       365         |
|      B      |       30          |

People Table:
| Person | ProductName | ReceiveDate |
| ------ | ----------- | ----------- |
| Name1  |      A      | 12-05-2020  |
| Name2  |      B      | 26-08-2020  |

My first intention is to create a query that calculates the Expiration Date, based in ReceiveDate and EstimatedDuration. After that I want to know all the products that have their expiration date in the next month for example.

The SQL code is:

```
SELECT [Products].[ProductName], [People].[ReceiveDate], [Products].EstimatedDuration, DateAdd("w",[Products].[EstimatedDuration],[People].[ReceiveDate]) AS ExpirationDate, DateDiff("d",Date(),[ExpirationDate]) AS Days
FROM [Products] INNER JOIN [People] ON [Products].ProductName= [People].[ProductName]
WHERE ((([Products].EstimatedDuration) Is Not Null)) AND ((DateDiff("d",Date(),[ExpirationDate]))<30));
```

The WHERE condition is because in my product table I don't have EstimatedDuration in all products.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: what data type is expirationdate?  what data type is received date?

Comment: Sorry for that! Already edited the question so it would be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the extended syntax:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Products].[ProductName], 
    [People].[ReceiveDate], 
    [Products].EstimatedDuration, 
    DateAdd("w",Nz([Products].[EstimatedDuration], 0),[People].[ReceiveDate]) AS ExpirationDate, 
    DateDiff("d",Date(),[ExpirationDate]) AS Days
FROM 
    [Products] 
INNER JOIN 
    [People] ON [Products].ProductName= [People].[ProductName]
WHERE 
    [Products].EstimatedDuration Is Not Null 
    AND 
    DateDiff("d",Date(), DateAdd("w",Nz([Products].[EstimatedDuration], 0), [People].[ReceiveDate])) < 30;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to copy your code and do the changes but it still gives me the same error of data mismatch

Comment: And what data type is your date fields? Also, double-check your data.

Comment: I defined the DateDiff (Days) field as general number. The other ones are all Dates (ExpirationDate and ReceiveDate). I believe that the only problem could be have some null values in EstimatedDuration but I'm filtering that information with the WHERE clause

Comment: OK. _Nz_ can take care of that. See edited answer, please.

Comment: It worked but now I'm receiving some of the information duplicated. Do you have any idea of why it might be happening?

Comment: Try using _group by_ or _distinct_.