Getting Data type mismatch in criteria expression when comparing DateDiff value to an integer
I am querying a table to get the start and end dates of a probation, then calculate the number of months until the halfway point, the date of the halfway point, and how many months that halfway point is from the present.
This is from a Microsoft Access format mdb database file, and I'm using MDB Viewer Plus to view and operate on the data. That program performs just fine for performing queries.
Here is a query that works, followed by a screenshot of an output table with accurate values. The data types are either date or number in this particular view.
select ReceiptDate,SupervisionTerminationDate 
, DateDiff("m",[ReceiptDate],[SupervisionTerminationDate]) as ProbationLength
, int(ProbationLength/2) as HalfProbationLength
, DateAdd("m",HalfProbationLength,[ReceiptDate]) as HalfProbationDate
, int(DateDiff("m",HalfProbationDate,NOW())) as HalfProbationMonthsTillNow
from list3
where len([SupervisionTerminationDate]) > 0 and len([ReceiptDate]) > 0
and Year([SupervisionTerminationDate]) > 2022


But now I need to find out how many months back from Now() or from Now() until the probation halfway point. I would use the aliases I set up for the col names, like "HalfProbationMonthsTillNow" as integers in a DateDiff() to simply add to or subtract from
Now(), but apparently MS Access doesn't allow variables to be declared, so I have to spell out the entire calculation, like so (it's the last line of the sql):
select ReceiptDate,SupervisionTerminationDate 
, DateDiff("m",[ReceiptDate],[SupervisionTerminationDate]) as ProbationLength
, int(ProbationLength/2) as HalfProbationLength
, DateAdd("m",HalfProbationLength,[ReceiptDate]) as HalfProbationDate
, int(DateDiff("m",HalfProbationDate,NOW())) as HalfProbationMonthsTillNow
from list3
where len([SupervisionTerminationDate]) > 0 
and len([ReceiptDate]) > 0
and Year([SupervisionTerminationDate]) > 2022
and DateDiff("m",DateAdd("m",DateDiff("m",[ReceiptDate],[SupervisionTerminationDate])/2,[ReceiptDate]),NOW()) < 9

...but when I run the query with that last line present, it throws a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error:

If I take away the comparator part of the last WHEN condition, and place it in one of the field lines, it outputs just fine. It looks like a proper integer. But when I compare it to an integer, like > 9 it throws the error.

Use NZ() on any field that could be null. This maybe be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575319/query-that-calculates-a-datediff-returns-a-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria

@BartMcEndree It does look very similar, thanks.

There were, indeed nulls in the SupervisionTerminationDate column that were causing the error. I tried Nz(), but that threw another error ("Undefined function 'Nz' in expression"). Since there were only 4 cells with null values, I filled those in and the query worked. Not a genius solution, but now I know the "why" of my problem.

Unfortunately, Nz does not work over ODBC. Instead use IIF(some_field Is Not Null, some_field, 0). It might be more convenient to use subqueries to filter out Null values, but the query optimizer may choose to ruin that approach

Try wrapping the division result in INT() due to odd number results since DateAdd requires an integer:
DateDiff("m",
  DateAdd("m",
    INT(DateDiff("m",[ReceiptDate],[SupervisionTerminationDate])/2),
    [ReceiptDate]
  ),
  NOW()
) < 9

